# Get Google Calendar API Limit

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

Is there any way to get the requests quota of **Google Calendar API** by calling some API method in code?

I know that I can see the total and remaining requests count on the project dashboard. But, I want to fetch it in my application and display it to admin user on a web page for convenience so that he doesn't need to sign in to Google to view the quota.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

No there is no way to see how much of the Quota you have used on any of the Google APIs. I normally keep a running count of requests for display to the user.   But there is no way to check what the over all quota usage is for the application.

I have done send feed back from the Developer console several times asking them to add an API.  There are cloud monitoring APIs but nothing for monitoring quota usage.